# Do all "meta" questions within philosophy reduce to descriptive and normative?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, metaphilosophy, concept

At first, under "meta" I, of course, mean such things as metaphilosophy, metaethics, and some other "metas" trying to answer the questions "What is X?", "What properties does X have?", etc. And this has nothing to do with stackexchange meta.

At first, I am starting from language analysis, it will be only brief explanation, because in fact that theory is very complex. I explain everything through the notion of "pattern"  Anything capable of affecting humans (and other sapient beings and maybe even all sentient beings) is a pattern. Patterns are objects, processes, images, letters, words, etc. But among them the very important one is "concept". To me a concept is a pattern occuring in a mind in a result of stimulation, as a response to other patterns.

Now, a few examples.

Suppose, a child point a finger to some object and asks what is it? What a child asks is in fact more precisely should be tracted as "What this pattern is called in our language?" Language is a social construct and then such a question is purely descriptive as it asks what do people in given society call a particular pattern.

Or suppose a person have heard the word but has no clue what does it refer to. This can be the case with neologisms. Then the reverse process is the case, but it still is purely descriptive: "What pattern does society call by given name?"

But now a thought experiment: if you teach a child that teapot-pattern (something that almost all english speakers call "teapot") is called "chair" then a child will call teapot-pattern a chair even among average people, who are not a part of the experiment. It would take a while for others to understand that a child calls teapot-pattern "chair" and even more to teach a child call teapot-pattern "teapot". This experiment shows that if the same pattern is called differently by different people it can lead to misunderstanding.

But now let's move to some very abstract notions such as "love", "god", "good", "bad", "evil", "philosophy", etc. The question "What pattern does society call "love"?" is not unambiguously answerable because there is no consensus on the meaning of this word. Just because they are so broad that people only concentrate on particular properties ignoring others when learning language (first language acquisition) which causes differences in understanding.

Therefore, all given explanations, by fact, will be definitions or personal beliefs. In the first case a person wants others to agree with given definition, often arguing with them, and thus it will be normative claim. In the second case it again is just a description of personal beliefs.

Then I would answer the question "What is love?" by "What you have learnt to call "love" in a descriptive manner escaping any "meta" debates on the meaning of words. Most people, of course, would just tell their understanding of what "love" is, but the answer might not satisfy the questioner and result in an argument.

Normative claims are not as much philosophy as ideology. So do "metas" reduce to descriptive philosophy (science?)?

*P. S. Metaphilosophy tag because there is a consensus that questions about philosophy are metaphilosophy, but I still think correct answers can be only descriptive.*

Comment: It may be just me, but I cannot quite understand what is being asked.

Comment: @PeterJ, as a narrow example, can we in fact call metaethics a branch of descriptive or normative ethics (or a variation of both)?

Comment: I'd say it depends how we do it. But 'meta-ethics' cannot be a branch of some other ethics since it is overarching. A difficulty here is that you assume (I think) that knowledge of these things (love, God, good, bad, etc) is impossible, This assumption is arbitrary and in my opinion wrong. If it is wrong then this would rather change the discussion.and the goalposts might need moving.

Comment: @PeterJ, it's not about knowledge. If you teach a child that teapot is called a chair a child would call teapot a chair. And otherwise, different patterns can be called the same name and that's what I mean here - all debates arise because different people refer to different patterns by the same names (and therefore are vacuous if they are not about facts).

Comment: I am having the same trouble as Peter. What would be an example of a "question" (in any field) that is neither descriptive nor normative? After all, all sentences are interrogative, imperative or indicative. Is emotive/evocative a different thing? Methodological? And why is "descriptive" identified with science (or vice versa)? Logical positivists' attempt to do so famously went down in flames because their own pronouncements on the matter did not qualify as scientific.

Comment: @Conifold, I thought that's the problem with philosophy of "meta" questions. They presuppose some kind of truth which can't be tested and therefore is not descriptive. Descriptive is identified with testable description, you can ask people's opinions on words, can ask them to give their explanations, that's scientific and testable.

Comment: This is too abstract. Much of science is methodological and/or theoretical, hence not "testable" in any direct sense, even the distinction between that and "descriptive" has been suspect since Quine. It is the outcomes of the entire enterprise that are "tested", and "meta" discourse contributes to that whether it is "descriptive" or not. In this sense science is not unique, all of culture is "tested" in a pragmatic sense, and outdated parts discarded. "Meta" is arguably closer linked to the "truth-apt" parts than, say, art or politics.

Comment: @Conifold, but I just can't see the distinction between descriptive philosophy and meta one. I'm quite sure they are indistinguishable because society itself creates some kind of consensus (or debate) on what is X, but then meta questions already are all answered, it appears.

Comment: @rus9384 - Maybe the problem here is the idea of philosophy as a language-game. It is exactly this, but the ideas of the game is to keep playing until it become clear what we are talking about. It's the same when physicists talk about 'dark matter' or when in algebra we perform calculations in order to reveal what our terms mean. We think about God or Love, say, in order to discover what we mean by these words. They cannot be descriptive at first but gradually they may become so. In philosophy such words are place-holders until we've done a lot of work.

Comment: @PeterJ, well, people don't have a single definition. To me love is the same as repeatedly occuring desire which is not necessarily tied to humans or living beings. Indeed, typically it requires some kind of trading (care, monet, etc.). Some people say that love is necessarily caring behaviour towards a person. To me it's just a small fraction of possible loves. Same for God, good, bad, etc.

Comment: @PeterJ, but then I should say all meta questions are meaningless: people can, at least temporarily, define something they are going to discuss and use old or maybe even new word for this. And no debates happen. The silliest debate is on meaning of words.

Comment: @rus9384 - Your idea of love is mundane but for some love is a greater and more important phenomenon with metaphysical and ontological significance. I don't know why you believe meta-question are meaningless or are against debating the meaning of words. I assume you are a logical positivist, which puts us in different camps.

Comment: @PeterJ, debates on words are meaningless simply because people themselves are the ones who define and give names. There, indeed, are some cases when debates about words are not silly: say, how to call a new product. And I know to some love is entirely different, that's exactly what I'm saying - different patterns are called the same by different people. But debates can be meaningful only on properties of these patterns, not on their names. Meta-questions are meaningless because they do not have any use. You can't predict anything with them, can't even share your ideas properly.

Comment: But they do have use, it's just that your idea of use is too narrow. "Sharing ideas properly" is overrated, what matters more is prompting and coordinating actions, vague words are blunt instruments but that is often enough. Whether to choose this or that notation, this or that theoretical generalization (say, relativity over ether) affects what and how is being done in science and outside of it. The idea of language as correlating words to "patterns" is a naivete from 19th century.

Comment: @Conifold, I mean it's impossible to discover meaning of words, only define them, this is normative theory. The only discovery possible is to understand what people mean when they use words, this is descriptive study.

Comment: There is no such thing as "meaning" of words, so there is nothing there to "understand".  "Meaning" is not a thing you treat it as just because it is grammatically a noun, and all "defining" words does is regulate their public use. There is nothing to be "discovered" beyond that. You really need to read modern philosophers of language, like [Wittgenstein](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein/#MeanUse), Austin and Grice.

Comment: @Conifold, but then, do really people understand each other on meta-questions? I feel like they are just using different definitions and then such converstaions are useless. And I don't reject Wittgenstein's meaning as use. I expand usefulness, not only in language, but everywhere: epistemology, science, ethics, etc. So, it's not new for me. But there is no use when people refer to different patterns (and don't understand it) when using the same words.

Comment: This is another empty question coming from the same confusion. All there is to people's "understanding", of *any* topic, is coordinating their public use of words, and other actions those words service. And since you still talk about patterns and definitions I am afraid you are missing Wittgenstein's point. "Using different definitions" is part of forging a common use that emerges as a result (ideally).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82948/discussion-between-rus9384-and-conifold).